# Extract image pixels of triangle Error

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm new to *image processing and development.* I need to take the inside triangle pixels of the image. In order to do it I used the following code. Unfortunately I obtain unwanted black pixels. get rid of that problem i tried to remove background[0] pixels by giving alfa value.(tranparent background) But it gives following Error. Any help is appreciated.

My code:

```
Mat img = cv::imread("/home/fabio/code/lena.jpg", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

Mat alpha(img.size(), CV_8UC1, Scalar(0));

//triangle definition (example points)
vector<Point> points;
points.push_back(Point(200, 70));
points.push_back(Point(60, 150));
points.push_back(Point(500, 500));

//apply triangle to mask
fillConvexPoly(alpha, points, Scalar(255));

cv::Mat finalImage = cv::Mat::zeros(img.size(), img.type());

img.copyTo(finalImage, alpha);

imshow("image", finalImage);

Mat dst;

Mat rgb[1];
split(finalImage, rgb);
Mat rgba[2] = { finalImage, alpha };
merge(rgba, 2, dst);

imshow("dst", dst);
```

Error: **OpenCV Error: Bad number of channels (Source image must have 1, 3 or 4 channels) in cvConvertImage, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\highgui\src\utils.cpp, line 611**

[image: What i need to do]

Comment: your input image is loaded as grayscale, that's why it isn't RGB but only a single channels. Adding the alpha channel will reach a 2 channel image which isn't displayable. Please keep in mind that openCV won't handle the alpha channel correctly during displaying with imshow, so better save as .png to test the alpha channel feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this instead of your last block:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> channels; 
cv::split(finalImage,m channels);
if(channels.size() == 0)
{
    std::cout << "unexpected error" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
// fill up to reach 3 channels
while(channels,size() < 3)
{
    channels.push_back(channels[0]);
}
// add alpha channel
channels.push_back(alpha); 
cv::merge(channels, dst);
```

I didn't test it but this should be what you want?

Comment: didn't see that your input image is grayscale... added more channels if necessary to reach RGBA

Comment: @Mika you're idea is i think correct ,Thank you for so much. But   code has small problem.
  `no instance of overloaded function "merge" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (std::vector<cv::Mat, std::allocator<cv::Mat>>, int, cv::Mat) c:\Users\ven\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\current_final\opencvtest\opencvtest.cpp 230`

Comment: @Mika No errors. But same result. nothing has changed. just lena image trangle with black pixels.

Comment: did you save it to png? OpenCV doesnt display alpha channek correctly

Comment: thank you when i save it i can see alfa effect. on the other hand when i reload that Mat again i see black '0' pixels. what i have lean't is  i think to remove black background from image , change the alfa value is not a solution.

Comment: you can't REMOVE the pixels. Images are always rectangular so there will always be some parts uncovered by your triangle. What do you want to show instead of the black pixels?

Comment: after I saved by using imwrite I saw the alpha effect. On the other hand, I reload the saved mat, still I'm having the black pixels. Seems like by changing the alpha value of image, might not be solution of removing black pixels. Could you please tell me good approach. Only isolating pixels inside Mat, and remove black mask pixels.

Comment: you can't... What do you want to do with the triangle? Typically for processing you'd use masks to not process unwanted pixel. For displaying you'd use a rendering engine and alpha channel. For printing you'd cut out the triangle with a scissor.